# A better db design for 1-to-many-to-many relationship?

Tags: database, design-patterns

I currently encounter a problem and wonder if there exists a better solution for this case. Initially I have three entities, A, B, and X. Their relationships are as follows.

- A-B: 1-to-many
- A-X: 1-to-many
- B-X: 1-to-many

For example, one row in A may associate with many rows in both B and X. Also, one row in B may have many other associated rows in X.

Some of the options I have considered:

1. Duplicate X

   So we have A-B, A-X1, and B-X2 in which X1 and X2 are identical, just different table name.
2. Use polymorphic association

   X now has two columns **parent** and **parent_id** indicating with which table, A or B, a row is associated.
3. Reverse the polymorphic association

   Two additional tables, AX and BX, are created. The relationship is straightforward.

   A--AX--X--BX--B
4. Use an additional foreign key for X.

   X now has two columns, **A_id** and **B_id**. If a row is associated with A, then **B_id** is null. If a row is associated with B, then **A_id** = A.id and **B_id** = B.id.

Of course they all have tradeoffs. I wonder if there are any better solutions for this problem. Please suggest any one you know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think #3 is your best option. The common db modelling term for that kind of relationship is [Junction Tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table). It is a very clean way for creating many-to-many relationships between tables. And as you said:

> The relationship is straightforward.

With junction tables you don't need to use duplicates (#1) or create flags indicating which table to link it to (#2) and #4 looks like a slightly different take on #2.

Many db modelers will bristle at the extra joins but as long as your indexes are set properly the model will be performant. And if you get tired of writing out joins, create some views.

Comment: Thanks, Paul. If not using option #3, then which option you think is the next candidate? The issue is that I have to try to reduce the number of join statements.

Comment: In that case #4 sounds like the next cleanest though #3 would reduce your joins further. Why are you have to worry about the number of joins?

Comment: I think #4 is the next best, too. Thanks! Actually, the design will later be used mostly by the report team, not developers. For historic reasons, they don't feel comfortable with data spread in multiple tables. The process of designing for the report team is that we come up with a strictly normalized design, and then they comment on it to suit their need (mostly denormalize the design). So, we usually make use/violate some anti-patterns like EAV or polymorphic association. But the team accepts the tradeoffs, so we go with that.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the feedback!